# Calculating angular acceleration c#

Tags: c#, math

I have two points. Each point has a course (degrees), and a speed (m/s).

These points come from a GPS file, and there are thousands of them.

I am trying to eliminate glitches from the file, bad data that is unbelievable. One way of doing this is to work out the angular acceleration of the change in speed and course between the two points and if it is over some kind of threshold, you can eliminate the point from the set as a piece of bad data (a spike in the gps.)

This worked fine when my points were 1 second apart, but now I'm dealing with points that are less than one second apart (typically .2 second) and more valid data are getting flagged as spurious. I'm wondering if I've done something wrong?

Here is the code I'm using:

```
  double radCourse2 = p1.Course*Math.PI/180;
  double radCourse1 = p2.Course*Math.PI/180;
  double vel1X = Math.Abs(p1.Speed*Math.Cos(radCourse1));
  double vel1Y = p1.Speed*Math.Sin(radCourse1);
  double vel2X = Math.Abs(p2.Speed*Math.Cos(radCourse2));
  double vel2Y = p2.Speed*Math.Sin(radCourse2);
  // secs is normally -1, but now sometimes -.2
  double secs = p1.CreationTime.Subtract(p2.CreationTime).TotalSeconds;

  double accX = (vel2X - vel1X)/secs;
  double accY = (vel2Y - vel1Y)/secs;

  // If p2.Acceleration is above about 5.5, then it is too fast.
  p2.Acceleration = Math.Sqrt(accX*accX + accY*accY);

  // Adjusting for deceleration vs acceleration
  if (p1.Speed > p2.Speed)
    p2.Acceleration *= -1;
```

Sample data. The three marked lines are out of bounds at the moment based on the code above.

```
Speed   course
12.06999973 135.459997
12.27999973 138.9399969
12.63999972 141.7999968
12.53999972 142.9699968
12.50999972 146.1299967
12.79999971 149.9399966
12.91999971 154.9699965 <--
12.95999971 157.0699965
13.11999971 163.3799963 <--
13.2399997  167.6799963
13.13999971 172.3599961
13.14999971 178.019996 <--
13.3799997  181.6499959
13.2799997  183.9299959
12.51999972 188.0699958
12.42999972 191.0599957
11.95999973 196.1499956
11.71999974 200.5499955
11.16999975 204.7399954
10.74999976 210.3599953
10.19999977 215.2699952
```

Comment: you can also try to calculate the angle using the `Math.Atan2`  function

Comment: Can't give any meaningful advice without seeing a typical plot of your course/speed data.

Comment: "angular acceleration of the change in speed and course": hem, what do you mean ?

Comment: If someone is travelling in a straight line and their speed jumps from 10m/s to 30m/s then back to 10m/s all over the course of three seconds, this would be an unreasonable acceleration followed by an unreasonable deceleration. Easy enough to work out in a straight line. However, if someone is travelling at a constant speed, but changing the angle of travel (the course) this also creates acceleration that can be unreasonable. If travelling at 10m/s, you can't change course quickly from say 120 degrees to 190 degrees then back to 115 degrees.

Comment: It's a long time since I wrote this code, and I'm wondering if there is a time factor missing. Previously when it was based on data usually 1s apart, not a problem, but now with 5 points per second, I am getting more false positives. I have checked the data by comparing files from the same trip with both 1s and .2 s intervals, and the results are not orders of magnitude different. (with 1s spread I might get a calculated acceleration of 5.5m/s2, with .2s spread I may get acceleration of 6.5m/s2 in the same bend) so I suspect I need to tweak my threshold rather than my algorithm, but...

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the quantity you are calculating is not angular acceleration. It's the magnitude of the linear acceleration vector - i.e. the magnitude of the acceleration, disregarding its direction. Angular acceleration would be the rate of change of the rate of change of `Course`. I *think* you'd need three data points to do this, but I haven't thought it through carefully. I don't think you are doing anything wrong, but the closer your data in time, the more susceptible they are to noise as you're dividing by a smaller quantity. Can write up as answer if you think this will help you.

Comment: That is helpful. I think. The noise comment makes sense. The changes in the speeds and courses look fairly regular in the data set, but when you run the calculations, lots of fluctuations appear.

Comment: I took a "Units" approach to it. The "Vel" value is in m/s, so the "Acc" value is in (m/s)/s or m/(s squared) which is an acceleration unit. That makes me think I haven't done anything wrong with the units. Probably just need to change the threshold to account for the time period.

Comment: Yes - your units and calculations are right.  It is acceleration, but not *angular* acceleration.  I'll write it up with an example if I get some time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not calculating *angular* acceleration, but rather simply acceleration.  More accurately, you are estimating the magnitude of it.  Initially, you were estimating d<sup>2</sup>s / dt<sup>2</sup> using `dt == 1` second.  Now you are estimating the same quantity using `dt == 0.2` seconds.

You can see the reason for your threshold being exceeded more often if you output the intermediate values for your calculations with both timesteps.  I've done that below:

```
t       Speed      course     Estimated  Estimated  Estimated acc   Estimated acc
                              velx       vely       (dt == 0.2)     (dt == 1)

0.000   12.070     135.460    8.466      -8.603
0.200   12.280     138.940    8.066      -9.259     3.843
0.400   12.640     141.800    7.817      -9.933     3.593
0.600   12.540     142.970    7.552      -10.011    1.379
0.800   12.510     146.130    6.972      -10.387    3.457
1.000   12.800     149.940    6.412      -11.078    4.449            5.092
1.200   12.920     154.970    5.466      -11.707    5.675
1.400   12.960     157.070    5.049      -11.936    2.380
1.600   13.120     163.380    3.753      -12.572    7.221
1.800   13.240     167.680    2.825      -12.935    4.981
2.000   13.140     172.360    1.747      -13.023    5.409            2.169
2.200   13.150     178.020    0.454      -13.142    6.490
2.400   13.380     181.650    -0.385     -13.374    4.356
2.600   13.280     183.930    -0.910     -13.249    2.699
2.800   12.520     188.070    -1.758     -12.396    6.011
3.000   12.430     191.060    -2.385     -12.199    3.286            2.277
3.200   11.960     196.150    -3.327     -11.488    5.902
3.400   11.720     200.550    -4.114     -10.974    4.701
3.600   11.170     204.740    -4.675     -10.145    5.006
3.800   10.750     210.360    -5.433     -9.276     5.768
4.000   10.200     215.270    -5.890     -8.328     5.261            4.346
```

This shows the values you highlighted as exceeding your arbitrary 5.5 threshold, but in the calculations with the longer timestep, all the intermediate values are ignored.  So, for instance, in the second between t==1.0 and t==2.0, there are two values at the 0.2 second timestep that exceed the threshold.  However, with the 1 second timestep, the estimate is well below the threshold for that timestep.

If your noise on each measurement is random and its magnitude is independent of the measurement interval (`dt`), then the smaller `dt`, the larger your expected error in estimated acceleration, as you are dividing by a much smaller number, so if you decrease `dt` by a factor of a fifth, you'd expect your error to be 5 times larger.  Note - this doesn't mean you'd expect the absolute value of acceleration to be 5 times larger, just the measurement error on it.

Comment: @DylanT does this answer the question?  If so, I'd appreciate it if you [voted / accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).  If not - please leave a comment and I'll try to address.

Comment: I've only just returned to this issue after a long break. I was about to repost on this question, when I located this answer. Thanks for the clear explanation, and my apologies for being so long responding to it! If all I care about in my analysis is whether my error boundaries are crossed, it would be sufficient to divide the calculated figure by 5 in this case?

Comment: @dylanT The closer in time your points are, the more noise you'd expect (roughly). In effect the points spaced at 1 second are averaging the noise over time vs those at 0.2 sec.  You could reasonably expect more points to exceed a fixed threshold with closer timing.  What you want to do depends on the application. If you're totally convinced that the fixed acceleration threshold indicates bad data, throw them out. Even if you throw out 50% of the 0.2 sec data points, you'll have far more good data than the 1 sec data even if all the points were "good". Otherwise, play with the threshold value.

Comment: Thanks. Out of curiosity, how WOULD you go about calculating a meaningful angular acceleration that takes into account the increased ? All I can find is calculations for centrifugal acceleration, but they need a radius, and all I have is two consecutive points with (sometimes) different courses and velocities

Comment: @dylanT it depends what your really want . If you want ***angular*** acceleration, that is the rate of change of angular velocity over time. In turn, angular velocity is the rate of change of heading (angle) with time.  So, you could produce an interim column of estimated angular velocities (doing same calculation for the angle column as you have for the speed) and then do the same calculation again on that column.  However - I suspect you might really be looking for ***centripetal*** acceleration, which you can ***estimate*** by multiplying the interim column by the original velocity column.

Comment: I was hoping to use same kind of logic, where I can calculate sharp lane change or rapid angular movement change from gps coordinates. Can you point me in some direction, how to get around with that?